# Return rows that have the minimum amount of missing values pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a table that has 5 rows and 10 columns:

- Row 1 has 3 missing values
- Row 2 has 2 missing values
- Row 3 has 8 missing values
- Row 4 has 5 missing values
- Row 5 has 2 missing values

I would like the function to return me row 2 & 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.isnull().sum(axis=1)` will return the number of missing values per rows.

`min(df.isnull().sum(axis=1))` will return the minimum missing values for a row

`df[df.isnull().sum(axis=1) == min(df.isnull().sum(axis=1))]` will return the rows that have the minimum amount of missing values

Answer (score 0):

Use isna().sum equals to to generate a boolean and then subset

```
df[df.isna().sum(1).eq(2)]
```